# Changing location of c3p0.properties and hibernate.properties

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I have a problem regarding the use of hibernate.properties and c3p0.properties.  I am dependent upon an API.  The API uses Hibernate.  As such the API has it's own hibernate.properties and c3p0.properties file included within its delivery jar.  I need to ensure I ignore these properties completely when instantiating my Hibernate SessionFactory.  I do need these files to remain available on the CLASSPATH so that the API I depend upon can be configured.  I simply need a way to instantiate my org.hibernate.SessionFactory so that it doesn't look at these files in any way.  I don't mind using an xml configuration or setting my  Hibernate properties manually.  I just need to ensure that the properties in hibernate.properties and c3p0.properties are not read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to do this you will have to use an XML hibernate config file. If both the `hibernate.properties` and `hibernate.cfg.xml` are present, the XML file will override the properties file.

You can find more information here: 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig

Note: your c3p0 properties can be defined in the same XML file.

Comment: This answer is accepted and downvoted. Why? Can I use it? Is it safe? Is it correct? If you downvote a answer TELL US WHY! Have balls and show yourself.